# Selecting options and filter values in select box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is when I select an option in anyone of the select box and then selecting another option in other Select box, the values are automatically changing. How can I solve this. I want to filter values according to my selection and display it in a table without using plugins.

```
Here is my code:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pW6P6/4/

Comment: When you change selection from any select box, you are reloading all select box and refiltering throw all g_Vehicle list. You would like to filter only current selection without reloading previous (already selected) options. You should rethink about your coding logic.

Comment: I agree with @roasted. in your fxnReLoading.... you are reloading all select values

Comment: without reloading how can i do filtering??

Comment: Use a cache system, i mean an array of objects as g_Vehicle that you will populate on each selection change and filtering throw this array. If selection for year (main selection) change, reload original list from g_Vehicle and refresh all select boxes.

Comment: @Chinnu, I'm on it. Need some time

Comment: @Chinnu Guess my code is working

Comment: @AkhilSekharan I'm checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whooo, thats a hell lot of code for such a small task...

anyways, in each of your "change-functions" you are reloading your other filter-selects. thats why the select boxes are reset

e.g:

```
fxnSelectMake = function () {
    $('#tableID tr').remove();
    g_newRows = "";
    $.each(g_Vehicle, function (index) {
        if (g_Vehicle[index].Make == $('#DropDown_Make').val()) {
            fxnCreateRow(g_Vehicle, index);
        }
    });
    $('#tableID').append(g_newRows);
    fxnReLoadingModelFilters();         // <-- this is what i mean
    fxnReLoadingSubModelFilters();      // <-- and this
    fxnReLoadingYearFilters();          // <-- and this

},
```

but this is only part one. your main problem is this piece of code:

```
$.each(g_Vehicle, function (index) {
  if (g_Vehicle[index].Make == $('#DropDown_Make').val()) {
    fxnCreateRow(g_Vehicle, index);
  }
});
```

your g_Vehicle-Object is still the TOTAL object here, and you are just checking for the current selected value (not for year and so on)

i have written a function "isInIndex" which checks all 4 current selected values, and only returns true, if the current vehicle row is valid for all 4 select boxes:

```
isInIndex = function(vehicle) {
  return ($("#DropDown_Year").prop("selectedIndex") === 0 || vehicle.Year === $('#DropDown_Year').val()) &&
      ($("#DropDown_Make").prop("selectedIndex") === 0 || vehicle.Make === $('#DropDown_Make').val()) &&
      ($("#DropDown_Model").prop("selectedIndex") === 0 || vehicle.Model === $('#DropDown_Model').val()) &&
      ($("#DropDown_SubModel").prop("selectedIndex") === 0 || vehicle.SubModel === $('#DropDown_SubModel').val())
}
```

then i call this function in each of your "change-functions":

```
$.each(g_Vehicle, function (index) {
  if (isInIndex(g_Vehicle[index])) {
    fxnCreateRow(g_Vehicle, index);
  }
});
```

the updated and working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pW6P6/10/

edit: there are probably a lot of optimization-possibilities in your code, one of them is that you should save your jQuery-Objects into variables, and work with them:

for example:

```
var $dropDownMake = $('#DropDown_Make');

// and later
$dropDownMake.val()
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Here select boxes are not filtering according to options.

Comment: what do you mean by that? what is the desired behaviour? in my updated fiddle the table is updating according to the selected values. eg. if i select year 2012, and Submodel d, then 2 rows are shown. if i remove the submodel filter (select first option in submodel select) 3 rows are shown (all entries for year 2012). just try the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pW6P6/10/

Comment: Ya u r correct. Table is updating but select box options were not updating. please check it once. Eg: if i select 2012 , make should be def, pqr, but it was showing all options.

Comment: your code is kind of chaotic. you should define the desired behaviour excactly, and throw this code away. pick part of this code and use it in your new code. if you dont want to use a plugin, put this code into a plugin (you will find patterns here: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns). but clearly you need to think about what your code has to do (eg. if a year was selected, could this selection be changed? if not you could just disable this box. and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I combined your sorting functions in to one function.

ie, 
fxnSelectYear, fxnSelectMake, fxnSelectModel, fxnSelectSubModel to **fxnUpdateGrid**

It will be better if you can combine your fxnReLoading.. functions to **one**.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atutoy/2/)

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask me questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conserve your logic. You can save the selected value before deleting each options and select it after you reiitialized your select values :

http://jsfiddle.net/pW6P6/9/

```
var selected = $('#DropDown_Year option:selected').val();
$('#DropDown_Year option[value]').remove();
iHtmlYear = fxnOptions(g_YearsArray);
$('#DropDown_Year').append(iHtmlYear);
$("#DropDown_Year option[value=" + selected + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

Comment: I will save the select values, but the grid is reloaded completely, guess @Chinnu needs to have a look at that

Comment: I want to filter the related options and table too.

Comment: So, why you do not use a plugin like http://datatables.net/. It would be faster and probably cleaner :D And precisely something like this example : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: With out using plugins I want to complete this.