# 2 Select boxes filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, drop-down-menu

I have read this tutorial for selectbox filter:
http://www.cssnewbie.com/intelligent-select-box-filtering/#.Uewddo30FGg
http://www.lessanvaezi.com/filter-select-list-options/
[Selecting options and filter values in select box jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836644/selecting-options-and-filter-values-in-select-box-jquery)

Some of example are very big, i have 2 selectboxes, in the first selectbox i have only 3 entrys, how can i at easiest method filter second selectbox, i have tried also this:

```
        function cascadeSelect(parent, child){
        var childOptions = child.find('option:not(.static)');
        child.data('options',childOptions);

        parent.change(function(){
                childOptions.remove();
                child
                .append(child.data('options').filter('.sub_' + this.value))
                .change();
        });

        childOptions.not('.static, .sub_' + parent.val()).remove();

    }

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    //$j(document).ready(function(){
        cascadeForm = $j('.cascadeTest');
        orgSelect = cascadeForm.find('.orgSelect');
        terrSelect = cascadeForm.find('.terrSelect');
        cascadeSelect(orgSelect, terrSelect);
    //});
```

That's work by me only if i call the file via "file" protocol, but not http...